# Php: Warning: Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected in

Tags: php

its unbeliveable. This is all I got, at the very first file which is executed:

```
header ("Pragma: public\r\nExpires: 0");die;
```

and the error?  Warning: Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected in ... WTF? I `var_dump()`-ed the included files, but it contain this file only.

Comment: What surprises you exactly? You sent two headers, and the message says you can use `header` function to send **ONE** header only. If you want to send `Pragma` and `Expires`, you use the `header` function twice. Once per header.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What is unclear about the error?

You have a new line here:

```
\r\n
```

You are trying to set two headers. You need two `header()` statements instead of one with a line break in the string.

```
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
die();
```